# Import Excel, Export CSV with PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

Due to restrictions I either need to use VB or PowerShell for this task.

I have an Excel that looks like:

```
ColumA,              ColumB,ColumC,ColumD,ColumE,ColumF
000|Txt,MoreTxt ,    ColumB,ColumC,ColumD,ColumE,ColumF
```

I read about import_csv -header, but I'm under to successfully do it. I'll post my script below. The export I expect is:

```
ColumA, ColumB, ColumC, ColumD, ColumE, ColumF
000,    ColumB, ColumC, ColumD, ColumE, ColumF
```

Only Colum gets modified, and I -only- need the digits from before that pipe. It also has to stay three digits, so 1 becomes 001, etc.

This is the script I modified based on some previous inquiries I saw, and the MS Tutorial.

```
   $file = import-csv "C:\path\to\my\file\test.csv"
    foreach ($row in $file){
        $tempfile = New-Object psobject -Property @{
            ColumA = $row. 'ListName'.substring(0,2)
            ColumB = $row. 'ColumB'
            ColumC = $row. 'ColumC'
            ColumE = $row. 'ColumE'
            ColumF = $row. 'ColumF'
        }
        $expandfile = @()
        $expandfile += $tempfile | select ColumA, ColumB, ColumC, ColumD,  ColumE, ColumF
    }
```

PS gives me both errors on not liking everything I have in quotes (Which I thought was the column name, but I guess not. And also a parse error on the entire array. Essentially the entire script.

**UPDATE**
Providing real examples of source.

```
"Tiam
Name",SiamName,Siam,Ciam,Piam,Liam,Niam,Diam
"002|City, State","City, State - Some text (15092)",1,"3,408",99,"3,408",780,22.89%
"009|City, State","City, State - Some Text (E) (15450)",1,"1,894",81,"1,894",543,28.67%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

```
$expandfile = Import-Csv "C:\path\to\my\file\test.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $_."Tiam`r`nName" = $_."Tiam`r`nName".SubString(0,3)
    $_
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip. Your minimized version of mine is actually much closer. No, the imported file is an Excel file. 

I'm now getting a mass warning for 'You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression' then ~10 "The property Colum1 cannot be found.

I essentially just have your shortened version but with my columns.

Comment: @DNorthrup sounds like you don't have the column names in the script matching the CSV file. Do the names have spaces in them? e.g. do they start or end with a space?

Comment: 2 of them had a space in the middle, but since I thought it might be that, I removed it. I also removed the non-sensical header I -was- telling it to ignore to see if that helped.

Comment: @DNorthrup `"a,b,c\`n1,2,3\`n4,5,6" | ConvertFrom-Csv | % {$_.b = 7; $_}` demonstrates it working in principle. I can only suggest you edit your original question with an actual copy/paste of the top couple of lines of your CSV, hopefully someone can see exactly what's going on.

Comment: That's true - Fair enough. I updated the original post with exact samples of the Import. Since it is an Excel by default they will all have double quotes - However it seemed to completely ruin the formatting when I put the quotations in the update.

Comment: @DNorthrup Tiam Name has a carriage return and newline in the column name. I've edited my answer... try that?