# CSV Not Exporting after merge

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40297592/import-excel-export-csv-with-powershell/40316361#40316361) and it got me on a very good track, however while trying to 'all in one' it, I ended up with an issue. I'm very close, but after testing numerous theories I'm starting to reverse what I need.

I have a multiple sheet Excel - I need to pull the first sheet, CSV-ify it, then remove the headers, then only get the first 3 digits from the first line.("List Name")

My PS is:

```
  #Create and get my Excel Obj
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$excel.visible=$false
$excel.DisplayAlerts=$false
$UserWorkBook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\path\to\file\CompleteTest.xls")

$UserWorksheet = $UserWorkBook.Worksheets.Item(1)

$hitlistCSV = "C:\path\to\file\BroadcastReport.csv" 
$xlCSV = 6  #changed-grav

#Save, close, and clean up
$UserWorksheet.SaveAs($hitlistCSV,$xlCSV) 
$UserWorkBook.close()
$excel.quit()
$excel = $null


$expandfile = "C:\path\to\file\BroadcastReport.csv"
(gc $expandfile | select -Skip 1) | sc $expandfile
Import-Csv $expandfile | ForEach-Object {
    $_."List Name" = $_."List Name".SubString(0,3)
    $_
}
$expandfile | Export-Csv "C:\path\to\file\BroadcastReport.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I've modified it a lot, and tried to make it single runnable to avoid schedule multiple BATs. Everything seems to work - It pulls the first sheet, renames it, and replaces the top line EVERY time I run the 2nd portion. However, the SubString portion isn't taking effect, nor am I getting a 'FileExport' file.

My last modification now makes it so everytime it replies that I need to 'supply an Input Object' so I feel like it has to do with function-izing it. For reference the line I need to split is double quoted because it has commas. Ex:

```
"123|ST,City"
```

I only need the 123. When I just import the file and run my ForEach function, the output is what I expect. Just saving it to the file isn't.

Thanks.

Welcome any input.

**XLS Source**

```
This is the header line I need to skip                                                  
List Name   Broadcast Name  ColumC  ColumD  Colum E ColumF  Colum G ColumJ                      
401|ST, City    ST, City - More Text(LSM) (16803)   1   854 73  854 233 27.28%                      
402|ST, City    ST, City - October (LSM) (16807)    1   851 57  851 186 21.86%
```

**CSV Source after XLS -> CSV**

One thing that is weird is that once it becomes a CSV, I'm left with ~6 fields of just commas. Example:

```
List Name,Broadcast Name,ColumC,ColumD,Colum E ,Colum,Colum F,ColumG,,,,,,
"402|ST,City","ST, City - More Text(ACR) (16803)",1,854,73,854,233,27.28%,,,,,,
"402|ST,City","City, ST - Text (LSM) (16807)",1,851,57,851,186,21.86%,,,,,,
```

**UPDATE:**

Added example, updated source - Column names keep a space where a space exists.
Broadcast Name column -does- have a comma in it, but I assume it's being exported with double quotes.

**RESOLUTION**

```
  #Create and get my Excel Obj
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$excel.visible=$false
$excel.DisplayAlerts=$false
$UserWorkBook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\path\to\file\ExcelBook.xls")

$UserWorksheet = $UserWorkBook.Worksheets.Item(1)

$hitlistCSV = "C:\path\to\file\Output.csv" 
$xlCSV = 6  #changed-grav

#Save, close, and clean up
$UserWorksheet.SaveAs($hitlistCSV,$xlCSV) 
$UserWorkBook.close()
$excel.quit()
$excel = $null


$expandfile = "C:\path\to\file\Output.csv" 

$report = get-content $ExpandFile | select -skip 1 | convertfrom-csv | ForEach-Object {
$_."List Name" = $_."List Name".SubString(0,3)
$_
}
$report | Export-Csv ""C:\path\to\file\Output.csv"  -force -NoTypeInformation
```

Issue was a slight modification to the export function being separated functions. I assume due to some sort of write lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on your last line, you are setting $expandfile to the return result of export-csv, it is prompting you to provide an input because it is trying to perform the export but is only provided with a path.  Just change the last line to
`$expandfile | Export-Csv "C:\Users\Donavin\Desktop\TXRH\FileExport.csv" -NoTypeInformation`

**EDIT**

Ok need to make a few more changes for things to work correctly, valid import/export code is below

```
$expandfile = "C:\path\to\file\BroadcastReport.csv"
(gc $expandfile | select -Skip 1) | sc $expandfile

Import-Csv $expandfile | ForEach-Object {
    $_."List Name" = $_."List Name".SubString(0,3)
    $_
} | Export-Csv "C:\path\to\file\BroadcastReport.csv" -force -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hey Mike - Thanks for your explanation. However, now for some reason it's erroring on 'Cannont process argument because the argument "name" is invalid"

I'm thinking it's referencing my Import_CSV and the space in List Name? Any insight on that regard?

Currently I am getting a file saved but it just says "Length" "43"

Comment: hmm that's strange, can you provide a sanitized version of your CSV file?  you can dummy up the data and only need a few lines, I'd just like to test/troubleshoot locally

Comment: ok I think I may have been a bit too quick on the draw, digging deeper in the code now and I noticed that the file you are saving from excel is not the file you are importing with `import-csv` is that intentional?

Comment: It was - I thought it'd have to be exported into a separate file.
FileA.XLS -> FileB.CSV -(Split)> FileC.CSV

Can I just do FileA.XLS -> FileB.CSV -(Split> FileB.csv?

Comment: I'm a bit confused now, you can use `export-csv -force` to overwrite the file but as of right now the file you are importing is not related the one your saving via excel.  Your saving to `"C:dir\to\file\Output.csv"` then importing `"C:\Users\Donavin\Desktop\TXRH\BroadcastReport.csv"`, Am I missing a step somewhere?  or are those file supposed to be unrelated?

Comment: I'm obviously confusing it.
It should become the same file. I see what you mean. I'm updating the source, and including the first ~2-3 lines.

Comment: I also added a clip of the first CSV export, since it seems off.

Comment: Awesome, I think were on the same page now. I've updated my answer with some additional code, you should be able to drop it in to replace the matching portion in your script.  If you have any questions about what I did please let me know in chat and I'll do my best to explain(may be a bit slow to respond tho, my workweek is about to end)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127408/discussion-between-dnorthrup-and-mike-garuccio).

Comment: Thanks again for resolving the issue, Mike!